# PIAAC replication example missing from asdfree book

Tags: r, survey

Anthony;

A colleague and I were looking to work through the PIAAC data with lowdown and see the Replication Example is blank ([see here](http://asdfree.com/programme-for-the-international-assessment-of-adult-competencies-piaac.html#replication-example-32)).  So we went to your [Rbloggers' post circa 2014](https://www.r-bloggers.com/analyze-the-programme-for-the-international-assessment-of-adult-competencies-piaac-with-r/) and the script links to scripts in this post also return nothing.

Thanks for any leads as to where they might be found, or if we should wait until the asdfree text's replication example is populated.

thanks!

Comment: the replication script is on the live site now.  the far upper left of the live site has the archived code as well.  thanks